# Dealing with power gamers

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic, problem-players

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Handle a Powergamer / Munchkin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-handle-a-powergamer-munchkin)

*I'm pretty sure this was asked before but I couldn't find it*

How do you deal with power gamers? That player who is clearly maxing skills or power and using loopholes in the system to create situation where he's clearly reate situations where he's on top of his things and really hard to challenge. Most of the time, power gamers will create more powerful character than the average player.

The obvious answer is: Send him something equally abusive; but I'm not a power gamer myself..so I'm not inclined to study the system and shop for the gear to be ready to deal with a character.